# glGetActiveAttrib on Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es2, ndk

In my code-base I need to link the vertex declarations from a mesh to the attributes of a shader. To do this I retrieve all the attribute names after linking the shader. I use the following code (with some added debug info since it's not really working):

```
int shaders[] = { m_ps, m_vs };
if(linkProgram(shaders, 2))
{
    ASSERT(glIsProgram(m_program) == GL_TRUE, "program is invalid");

    int attrCount = 0;
    GL_CHECKED(glGetProgramiv(m_program, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &attrCount));

    int maxAttrLength = 0;
    GL_CHECKED(glGetProgramiv(m_program, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_LENGTH, &maxAttrLength));

    LOG_INFO("shader", "got %d attributes for '%s' (%d) (maxlen: %d)", attrCount, name, m_program, maxAttrLength);

    m_attrs.reserve(attrCount);

    GLsizei attrLength = -1;
    GLint attrSize = -1;
    GLenum attrType = 0;

    char tmp[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < attrCount; i++)
    {
        tmp[0] = 0;
        GL_CHECKED(glGetActiveAttrib(m_program, GLuint(i), sizeof(tmp), &attrLength, &attrSize, &attrType, tmp));
        LOG_INFO("shader", "%d: %d %d '%s'", i, attrLength, attrSize, tmp);
        m_attrs.append(String(tmp, attrLength));
    }
}
```

`GL_CHECKED` is a macro that calls the function and calls `glGetError()` to see if something went wrong. This code works perfectly on Windows 7 using [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) and gives this this output:

```
info:shader: got 2 attributes for 'static/simplecolor.glsl' (3) (maxlen: 11)
info:shader: 0: 7 1 'a_Color'
info:shader: 1: 10 1 'a_Position'
```

But on my Nexus 7 (1st gen) I get the following (the errors are the output from the GL_CHECKED macro):

```
I/testgame:shader(30865): got 2 attributes for 'static/simplecolor.glsl' (3) (maxlen: 11)
E/testgame:gl(30865): 'glGetActiveAttrib(m_program, GLuint(i), sizeof(tmp), &attrLength, &attrSize, &attrType, tmp)' failed: INVALID_VALUE [jni/src/../../../../src/Game/Asset/ShaderAsset.cpp:50]
I/testgame:shader(30865): 0: -1 -1 ''
E/testgame:gl(30865): 'glGetActiveAttrib(m_program, GLuint(i), sizeof(tmp), &attrLength, &attrSize, &attrType, tmp)' failed: INVALID_VALUE [jni/src/../../../../src/Game/Asset/ShaderAsset.cpp:50]
I/testgame:shader(30865): 1: -1 -1 ''
```

I.e. the call to `glGetActiveAttrib` gives me an `INVALID_VALUE`. The [opengl docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetActiveAttrib.xml) says this about the possible errors:

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if program is not a value generated by OpenGL.

This is not the case, I added an ASSERT to make sure `glIsProgram(m_program) == GL_TRUE`, and it doesn't trigger.

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if program is not a program object.

Different error.

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if index is greater than or equal to the number of active attribute variables in program.

`i` is 0 and 1, and the number of active attribute variables are 2, so this isn't the case.

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if bufSize is less than 0.

Well, it's not zero, it's 256.

Does anyone have an idea what's causing this? Am I just lucky that it works in ANGLE, or is the nvidia tegra driver wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I found that calling `glDetachShader(...)` on the vertex shader before `glGetActiveAttrib(...)` will lead to the results I saw. I can't find anything about this in the docs, so I assume it's implementation specific.

The solution is to get all the data you need before detaching the individual shaders.

Comment: Why are you calling glDetachShader? You do not need to detach the shader from the program until/if you release your gl resources.

Comment: The following question contains argument for why it's a good idea: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47910/after-a-succesful-gllinkprogram-should-i-delete-detach-my-shaders

Comment: @user408952: You have taken that question out of context. What you want to do is ***delete*** your shader after you compile and attach it. This ensures that after all of the GLSL programs that use the shader have been destroyed, the shader itself also is. Otherwise, shader objects tend to leak in OpenGL. But if you detach the shader and then delete it, you have first invalidated your GLSL program and then if the reference count for your shader is **0** at that point, you also deleted your shader.

Comment: @user408952: Deleting a shader does not actually do anything until the shader's reference count reaches **0**. That happens once it has been detached from all GLSL programs, until that point the shader is basically put onto a list of objects *to be* deleted. Detaching is very different from deleting, and it will break your GLSL program if you try to continue using the program while one of its linked shaders is detached.

Comment: This is the link I meant to post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113154/proper-way-to-delete-glsl-shader which says that "Yes -- in fact it is highly desireable to detach and delete your shader objects as soon as possible. That way the driver can free up all the memory it is using to hold a copy of the shader source and unlinked object code, which can be quite substantial."

Comment: Read the second comment to that answer you listed, to understand why you don't want to do that. Deleting without detaching is fine, but detaching is setting things up for disaster.